# Java XML Schema validator with custom resource resolver fails to resolve elements

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

Java XML Schema validation - ResourceResolver trouble

I am trying to build a component into a web application that will validate different XML documents against a set of schemas.

I have the validator class in java package com.example.xml and then I have a "package" for the schemas com.example.xml.Schemas where they are organized according to the namespace along with any included schemas, like so:

```
com.example.xml/SchemaValidator.java

com.example.xml.Schemas/2008/07/05/Message.xsd
com.example.xml.Schemas/2008/07/05/Person.xsd
com.example.xml.Schemas/2008/07/05/Address.xsd

com.example.xml.Schemas/2010/09/21/Message.xsd
com.example.xml.Schemas/2010/09/21/Organization.xsd
com.example.xml.Schemas/2010/09/21/Person.xsd
com.example.xml.Schemas/2010/09/21/Address.xsd
```

So most of the document-elements are called Message but in different namespaces and different internals.
Via a mapping I can determine where the correct schema is located, and then I load the XSD matching the root element name - but to make the parser able to read the included schemas, I made an attempt at an org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver implementation to fetch the correct files based on the systemId.

```
public class ResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver {
    private String basePath;

    public ResourceResolver( String baseDirectory ){
        basePath = baseDirectory;
        if( !basePath.endsWith("/")){
            basePath += "/";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
        System.out.println("Resolving: " + type + ", " + namespaceURI + ", " +  publicId  + ", " + systemId + ", " + baseURI + " (basepath:" + basePath + ")");
        String mypath = basePath + systemId;
        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(mypath);
        if( resourceAsStream == null){ System.out.println("Ups! Stream is null"); }

        String contents = null;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = new byte[resourceAsStream.available()];
            resourceAsStream.read(bytes);
            contents = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) { } 
        finally{
            try { resourceAsStream.close(); } 
            catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        Input xmlInput = new Input(resourceAsStream, type, namespaceURI, publicId, systemId, basePath);    
        xmlInput.setStringData(contents);  // avoid problems with inputstream position
        return xmlInput;
    }
}
```

And my ResourceResolver is used this way:

```
public boolean validate(Document doc, String xsdPath) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    String rootElmtName = doc.getDocumentElement().getLocalName();
    String resourcePath = "/com/example/xml/" + xsdPath ;
    InputStream topSchema = getClass().getResourceAsStream(xsdPath + "/" + rootElmtName + ".xsd");
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(topSchema);
    ResourceResolver resolver = new ResourceResolver(resourcePath);
    schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(resolver);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setResourceResolver(resolver);
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

    ValidationErrorHandler handler = new ValidationErrorHandler();
    validator.setErrorHandler(handler);
    validator.validate(source);
    if(handler.hasErrors()){
        for( ValidationError e : handler.getErrors()){
            log(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, it doesn't work!
It resolves a few schema resources and then stops 
I tried setting a breakpoint in Eclipse in my resource resolver, and the inputstream is not null - it points to the right file containing a XSD. So something in the Java XML parser classes must expect some other behavior from my resolver.

```
Resolving: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, http://com/example/xml/schemas/2005/08/07/, null, Letters.xsd, file:///com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/Message.xsd (basepath:/com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/)
Resolving: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, http://com/example/xml/schemas/2005/08/07/, null, GeneralElements.xsd, file:///com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/Message.xsd (basepath:/com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/)
Resolving: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, http://com/example/xml/schemas/2005/08/07/, null, GeneralTypes.xsd, file:///com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/Message.xsd (basepath:/com/example/xml/Schemas/2005/08/07/)
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'Letters' to a(n) 'group' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:2537)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:2528)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDGroupTraverser.java:72)
```

The contents of the Message.xsd contains a bit like this:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Letters.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="GeneralElements.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="GeneralTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="Message">
```

-and the Letters.xsd also contains

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="GeneralElements.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="GeneralTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:group name="Letters">
```

The outline is of the ResourceResolver and Input classes are from another SO post - so I might have misunderstood something.

Is it the proper way I have created the resource resolver, or have I missed something completely?